# jq command for getting root element inside an inner list

Tags: json, jq

This is my sample json

```
{
  "parent": {
    "rootElement": "root",
    "innerList": [
      {"id": 1, "value": "A"},
      {"id": 2, "value": "B"},
      {"id": 3, "value": "C"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I want a transformed json like this using jq commands

```
{"innerList": [
        {"id": 1, "rootElement": "root", "value": "A"
        },
        {"id": 2, "rootElement": "root", "value": "B"
        },
        {"id": 3, "rootElement": "root", "value": "C"
        }
    ],
 "rootElement": "root"
}
```

I tried this command but I dont get the desried output as I am not able to access the root element once I inside parsing the inner list.

`jq '{rootElement: .parent.rootElement, innerList: [.parent.innerList[] | {id, value: .value, rootElement: .parent.rootElement}]}'`

I get

```
{"innerList": [
        {"id": 1, "rootElement": null, "value": "A"
        },
        {"id": 2, "rootElement": null, "value": "B"
        },
        {"id": 3, "rootElement": null, "value": "C"
        }
    ],
 "rootElement": "root"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a jq variable in this and similar cases makes for an easy-to-read solution:

```
.parent
| .rootElement as $rootElement
| .innerList[] += {$rootElement}
```

Or, if you want the .rootElement key to appear first in the outermost object, change the last line above to:

```
| .innerList[] |= {$rootElement} + .
```

Comment: What if I don't want the whole inner list instead only the value from innerList and rootElement with it @peak

Answer (score 2):

After `.parent.innerList[] |` your context isn't the root anymore. Access `rootElement` outside the iteration:

```
.parent | .innerList[] += {rootElement}
```

```
{
  "rootElement": "root",
  "innerList": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "A",
      "rootElement": "root"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "B",
      "rootElement": "root"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "C",
      "rootElement": "root"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rEHwf3WPbNj)